# remove all leading and trailing spaces in xml document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way that I can remove all leading and trailing spaces in the elements and attributes in an xml document, using xslt?

```
<Root>
  <a>string    </a>
  <b r="another   ">second    </b>
</Root>
```

expected output

```
<Root>
  <a>string</a>
  <b r="another">second</b>
</Root>
```

Note: This is a sample xml, and i have many elements and attributes in my source xml document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you use the `normalize-space()` function the result is the string with all leading and trailing white-space characters removed**.

**However**, it also replaces any group of intermediary white-space characters with a single space character.

**If you don't want the last-mentioned effect, then one solution is to use the `trim` template function of FXSL 1.x** (FXSL written entirely in XSLT 1.0).

Here is a small example of using the `trim` template/function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <!-- to be applied on trim.xml -->

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(/*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<someText>

   This is    some text   

</someText>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
'This is    some text'
```